# Static analysis framework for eclipse?

Tags: code-analysis, eclipse-tptp

i just wanted to use eclipse tptp, a framework for static code analysis but the support for code analysis ended with tptp 4.5.0. 
1. it seems that this version can not be integrated into the current eclipse galileo.  am i right?
2. which language independant framework for eclipse would you use as an alternative for tptp static analysis which works with eclipse galileo?

Answer (score 2):

I confirm the "Static Analysis" module of TPTP has been moved to [the "as Is" (dormant) projects list](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/?ver=4.5.0#AsIsComponents), with a special [set of instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/platform/documents/gettingstarted/Static_Analysis_Getting_Started.html).

See [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tptp/msg07256.html):

> The owner of the static analysis component no longer work and contriube 
>   resource in the project and due to the lack of additional resources to 
>   support the component, PMC has decided to move it to as-is and there will be 
>   no maintenance on the component supported by the project.

I do not know about another *language independent* framework for a static analysis tool on Eclipse.
Tools for Java are many, [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html) being a good example (or Checkstyle, or PMD).
But for any language... I don't find any.